# How do you log a manually raised exception in an if statement in python

Tags: python, exception

Put simply, I have a piece of code that looks like this:

```
if some_condition_that_evals_to_True:
    raise ValueError("Error message")
```

What I want to do is to insert a logging statement that logs this entire exception but doing it just this way only saves the logger message:

```
if some_condition_that_evals_to_True:
    logger.error("Logged error message")
    raise ValueError("Error message")
```

Any one know how to save the entire error message including the ValueError?

EDIT:

The following is what I am trying to recreate:

```
if some_condition_that_evals_to_True:
    try:
        raise ValueError("Error with value")
    except ValueError:
        logger.exception("Logging Error with Value")
        raise
```

But this seems like a roundabout way to get the behavior I want, so another way to phrase my question: Is there a more elegant way get the same behavior as the above codeblock?

Comment: What *actually* happened when you tried this?  Show the actual output, and how it differs from what you wanted.  In short, don't ask *us* whether it will work, ask the ultimate authority: your Python run-time system.  :-)

Comment: @Prune Tried it and got the expected result and I edited the description to reflect that

Comment: Great.  Try an exception handler for `ValueError` and log what you like in that.  Will that work for you?

Comment: @Prune Are you saying insert a try-except on the inside of the if statement with just the raised error and catch the exception that way?

Comment: No, I was suggesting that you put the handler in the routine that calls this one.  If it were as simple as adding a line or to in the current `if` I trust that you would have already tried that.

Comment: Oh I see. Yes that could work. I was wondering though if the logging can be done at this level and not have be deferred upwards to the higher level call.

Comment: An exception can be handled gracefully without being a fatal error or showing up in any logs; `raise`ing an exception is just a mechanism to move execution control back to a caller in a specific way. In that sense, what exactly do you want to log here and for what purpose? You can log a warning and a stacktrace, and then still separately decide whether to `raise` an actual exception or not…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the `stack_info` keyword argument when using the [logging module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html):

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log',level=logging.DEBUG)
if True:
    logging.error('Error Message', stack_info=True)
    raise ValueError('Custom Error Message')
```

Running this shows the following:

```
J:\>python log_stack.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "log_stack.py", line 5, in <module>
    raise ValueError('Custom Error Message')
ValueError: Custom Error Message

J:\>more example.log
ERROR:root:Error Message
Stack (most recent call last):
  File "log_stack.py", line 4, in <module>
    logging.error('Error Message', stack_info=True)
```

Comment: This is almost exactly what I was hoping for. Is there a way log that the the ValueError is what caused the error? Essentially just log what is printed

Comment: @Abdullah The `ValueError` didn't cause the error, `ValueError` is merely is mechanism to inform other code of the specific error type. Your log message should be informative for humans, so a log message like `'Invalid value %r for foo' % foo` should give you all the information you need.

Comment: @Abdullah you are able to instantiate an exception, e.g. `e = ValueError('custom')` and then log that using `logging.exception(e, stack_info=True)`, however the documentation says that should only be called from an exception handler (I don't know the specific reasons), which is why I haven't used it above. It works in our trivial example.